# Why is my useEffect not being called when I take a item out of my cart in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am doing a simple food ordering web app with React and for some reason, I can't get my useEffect to run when the cart is changed with the X button to delete an item from the cart. This is true for both the heading cart counter and for the total amount. Both of these change when I am adding the item to the cart, but don't decrement with the remove button. I am able to delete the item from the cart and the state, but still nothing. I have tried changing my useReducer to it, but still nothing. Any help would be wonderful.

```
const initialState = 0;

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action) {
    case "increment":
      return state + 1;
    case "decrement":
      return state - 1;
    case "reset":
      return initialState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const CountContext = React.createContext();

const Home = (props) => {
    const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
    const [count, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    const {isVisible, toggleModal} = useModal();

    let totalPrice;

    let cartCounter ;

    const cartUpdaterHandler = (cartItem) =>{
        setCart([...cart, cartItem]);
        cartItem= cartItem;
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        cartCounter = cart.length;
        totalPrice = cart.reduce((acc, {price}) => parseFloat(acc) + parseFloat(price), 0).toFixed(2);
    }, [cart, cartCounter])

    const modalHandler = () => {
      toggleModal(true)
    }

    const removeCI = ( cartItemId) => {
      setCart(cart.filter((cartItem) => cartItem !== cartItemId))
      cartCounter = cart.length -1
      console.log(cartCounter)
    }

    return (
        <CountContext.Provider 
          value={{ countState: count, 
          countDispatch: dispatch, 
          currentCart: cart
          }}
          className={classes.contextProvider}
          >
          {isVisible && (
            <CartModal 
              overlayClassName="custom_overlay"   
              isVisible={isVisible} 
              hideModal={toggleModal} 
              currentCart={cart} 
              totalPrice={totalPrice}
              remove={removeCI}
              />
          )}
            <Header cart={cart} cartCounter={cart} modal={modalHandler}/>

            <Intro />
            <MealForm onAdd={cartUpdaterHandler} />
            {/* <Cart /> */}
            {/* <CartModal isVisible={isVisible} hideModal={toggleModal} currentCart={cart} totalPrice={totalPrice}/> */}
        </CountContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default Home;

const CartHeader = (props) => {
    const [modal, setModal] = useState(false)
    const {isVisible, toggleModal} = useModal();

    // const cartCtx = useContext(CartContext);
    const countContext = useContext(CountContext);

    const curCart = [props.cart]

    return (
        <React.Fragment >
            <CartIcon />
            <a onClick={props.modal}>Your Cart</a>
            {/* <CartModal isVisible={isVisible} hideModal={toggleModal}  /> */}
            {/* <div className='cart-header-number'>{props.counter}</div> */}
            <div className='cart-header-number'>{countContext.countState}</div>


        </React.Fragment>
    )

}

export default CartHeader;
```

Comment: Create `cartCounter` state variable I think it will solve your problem

Comment: @sodhankit I have moved my cartCounter to a state variable, but unfortunately, it still doesn't decrement my badge number. I am confused on why it will increment it and not the opposite.